# Is Application.Windows collection treated like a stack?

Tags: wpf

I am currently getting the active window so that I can render a custom alert on top of it.

`var activeWindow = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsActive)`

There are times that the activeWindow property returns null, even though I have a window w/ focus.

My question is, does the `Windows` collection stack windows or is there no guarantee of the order? Is it safe that

**Edited** *Removed lambda that should not have been there*

`var activeWindow = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().LastOrDefault()`

Will return the last Window opened?

Comment: do you by any chance call this from background thread?

Comment: I can't remember now, but an alert could be pushed with the app not being active so even if it's on the UI thread it would return null because it's no longer active. Looking to see if LastOrDefault is safe to use in general as a fallback if IsActive is false on all Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the order of the the windows is determined by the time of creation, and does not change when windows become active/inactive.

So `LastOrDefault()` does not return the last Window opened, it returns the window whose constructor is called most recently.

You need to do it yourself, in App.cs, add a reference to the last opened window, and update the reference when a window becomes active. And when you want to display the alert, first activate that window if it is not active.

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I should clarify. `LastOrDefault()` instead of `LastOrDefault(x => x.IsActive)` should return a Window regardless if it is active or not. What I am asking is `LastOrDefault()` with out a condition, will the Last item in the unfiltered collection be the last window opened?

Comment: Basically, if the last window opened _was_ active, and looses focus, is it safe that just `LastOrDefault()`, with out a lambda, will return the last window opened?

Comment: Refer to [Application.Windows Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.windows(v=vs.110).aspx), in the Remark section, the order of the Windows is based on the time a window is instantiated, not the time a window is last opened.

Comment: Ok, that will still work for me then, as my windows are instantiated and shown immediately. The work flow prevents another window opening until the newly instantiated one is Shown. This should allow me to attach an alert to the last opened window, as only 1 window at a time can be active; they're all shown modal